# jquery .hover() confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently programming my portfolio page and I came across a strange behaviour off hover states that I don't understand.
I have some links in a navigation bar at the top of my page. The links are fully defined with :hover and everything. Now I also want the colour of the links to change when I hover the mouse over the different sections of the site that the links refer to.
So I wrote this:

```
/* Navlink colors */
$('#portfolio').hover(function() {
       $('#portLink').css('color','#FF9900');
    }, function() {
       $('#portLink').css('color','inherit');
});
$('#about').hover(function() {
       $('#aboLink').css('color','#FF9900');
    }, function() {
       $('#aboLink').css('color','inherit');
});
...
```

At first it seems to work, but when you scroll to the blog and then move the mouse over the navigation the css :hover doesn’t seem to work anymore. This is my test site:

http://www.henning-marxen.de/test/index.html (Don't laugh those are placeholders^^)
Do you know why it behaves like this? I am very confused. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please check your HTML markup. I feel that you have used #portLink in href instead it should be like as <a id="portLink" ....

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue on chrome win7

Comment: No there is an Id="portLink" and an href="#portfolio" the anchor link is supposed to be there. @Wolff Hmm it doesent seem to work in chrome.

Comment: Also, the `font` tag is deprecated.

Comment: Why do this with jQuery? ... you can use the CSS pseudo-class `:hover` to much more easily achieve this.

Comment: Ah sorry I didnt't have the newest verion online. Now you can try it. @Stuart sadly no #portLink is no descendant of #portfolio.

Comment: @H.Marxen My bad, I didn't understand your issue at first

Comment: @H.Marxen I see... it's still hard to imagine a scenario where it would make *more* sense to do this in JS than CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mix of js and css for this. In your css you need to apply your styles with the hover state but also with a class which I'll call `current` for this example.

```
.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link.current{
  color:#FF9900;
}
```

Then all you javascript needs to do is add or remove the class depending on which part of the site you have scrolled to:

```
var navLinks = $('.nav-link');

//each time the user scrolls, reset all links by removing class.
navLinks.removeClass('current');

//Then find the link that needs highlighting and add the class to it.
//There obviously needs to be some logic here to filter the correct link.
navLinks.filter('[href="#portfolio"]').addClass('current');
```

Comment: Thank You!!!!!!!!!11111eleven I just replaced .css() with .addClass() and .removeClass(). Using filters etc. is probably more elegant, but it works now.^^ THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS for this, not jQuery:

```
#portLink:hover, #about:hover { color: #FF9900; }
```

Or (to more explicitly match your JS):

```
#portfolio:hover #portLink, #about:hover #aboLink { color: #FF9900; }
```

If your link elements are **not** descendent of those first selectors, use `+` to group them (as indicated in this fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/B8Xuw/ *note this assumes they are siblings rather than parent>child

```
#portfolio:hover + #portLink, #about:hover + #aboLink { color: #FF9900; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 /* Navlink colors */
    $('#portfolio').hover(function() {
       $('[href="#portfolio"]').css('color','#FF9900');
    }, function() {
       $('[href="#portfolio"]').css('color','inherit');
    });
    $('#about').hover(function() {
       $('[href="#about"]').css('color','#FF9900');
    }, function() {
       $('[href="#about"]').css('color','inherit');
    });
```